# Modifying an opened folder path

Tags: c#, path, directory, explorer

Let's say the user has an opened explorer window with the folder `W:\abc` opened on it.

I have two questions:

1. Can I know if the folder `W:\abc` is currently opened?
2. Can I change the path of the currently opened folder? For example make it `W:\`?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is possible. I don't know of a way of interacting with a running Explorer process in this way.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, it depends on your OS version, but I have used the [Shell Document Viewer](http://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/ie/shdocvw/) to get a list of all of the currently open shell windows on my system in the past. You can then filter the shellWindows list accordingly.

```
SHDocVw.ShellWindows shellWindows = new SHDocVw.ShellWindowsClass();

string fileName;

foreach ( SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ie in shellWindows )
{
    fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension( ie.FullName ).ToLower();

    if ( fileName( "explorer&quot; ) )
        Console.WriteLine( "Explorer looking at : {0}", ie.LocationURL );
}
```

An alternative is to get a list of all of the running processes, filter for explorer.exe and you could get the currently opened path using [Process.MainWindowTitle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowtitle.aspx) like this:

```
var processList = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach (Process process in processList)
{
    // do something here with process.MainWindowTitle
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but you need to use a lot of calls to native code. Raymond Chen has an example of how to do this with direct WinAPI calls in C:

[Querying information from an Explorer window](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/20/188696.aspx)

I've not fully evaluated the code, but I'm pretty confident it could be converted to C#. You'll need a significant amount of knowledge of P/Invoke and C to do so though.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can enumerate all opened instances of Explorer and compare your folder with current folder of every instance of Explorer. [Sample of enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22286658/2855440).

2) You can call [BrowseObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775113%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method of IShellBrowser object to navigate to new folder. Sample:

```
procedure BrowseToFolder(AShellBrowser: IShellBrowser; const AFolder: UnicodeString);
var
  DesktopFolder: IShellFolder;
  Eaten: DWORD;
  IDList: PItemIDList;
  Attr: DWORD;
begin
  SHGetDesktopFolder(DesktopFolder);
  try
    Attr := 0;
    OleCheck(DesktopFolder.ParseDisplayName(0, nil, PWideChar(AFolder), Eaten, IDList, Attr));
    try
      AShellBrowser.BrowseObject(IDList, SBSP_ABSOLUTE);
    finally
      CoTaskMemFree(IDList);
    end;
  finally
    DesktopFolder := nil;
  end;
end;
```