# Delphi TOpenDialog/TSaveDialog last used path

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

Referring my question to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4016075/698266, in particular step 3 says "Otherwise, if the application has used an Open or Save As dialog box in the past, the path most recently used is selected as the initial directory."

**Where does Windows save this information?**

Note: by experimenting, it seems to be linked to the application file name *without its path* - i.e. the same executable copied in different directories "sees" the same last path information, while changing the exe file name makes the dialogs point to the user's Documents directory.

My actual interest is for testing purposes. I need to "reset" this information in order to test my application in conditions similar to a first run.

Comment: It is undocumented where this information is saved, it could change from version to version. I suppose what you are really interested in is the rules for identification of your application. Right? And this isn't a Delphi question at all. It's pure Win32.

Comment: Yes, I know it's not strictly Delphi, but I'm using Delphi and its TOpen/SaveDialog and I can see this behaviour while working in this environment. And NO, I'm not interested in the rules for identification of my app. I'll edit the question to specify what's my intention.

Comment: Also, it's not important for me if the location changes from version to version, I'll just adapt to the new palces in that cases. I'm simply trying to reset this location "by hand".

Comment: Just export HKCU before and after you run your app changing the directory. Then compare.

Comment: Did it in another way: saved into a directory with a unique name, then searched for that name in the registry (using a registry editor that can search binary data, 'cause of the UNICODE encoding), et voilà!

Comment: A more direct solution would have been to use [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) and filter it on your EXE. Then it would show you the exact Registry key(s) and values being accessed by the EXE in real time.

Comment: Just use a virtual machine and save yourself the troubles of manually resetting the environment every time (and possibly doing it wrong). Virtual machines usually have a feature to save a snapshot of the system at any point in time and restore it at a later time.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yeah, didn't think about Process Monitor, it would probably have been a faster way.

Comment: @zett42 a VM would be a great solution for my actual problem, but unfortunately I haven't one I can use for that purposes (windows licenses aren't free).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows XP uses `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32\LastVisitedMRU` and the format of each item seems to be ExeFilename+Path with both strings zero terminated and in UTF-16LE format. The MRU list is stored as a string named `MRUList`.

[image: WinXP regedit]

Newer versions of Windows uses `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32\LastVisitedPidlMRU` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32\LastVisitedPidlMRULegacy` and the format seems to be ExeFilename+[ItemIdList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774508/persist-a-pidl-itemidlist) (ExeFilename in UTF-16LE and zero terminated). The MRU list seems to be a list of DWORDs in a binary value named `MRUListEx` and the list is terminated by 0xffffffff.

I would assume that the change happened in Vista because that is when the new [IFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776913(v=vs.85).aspx) was added. LastVisitedPidlMRULegacy is probably used when GetOpen/SaveFileName is called with a custom template and/or hook function.

Comment: Complete answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the answer myself.

For Windows 10 (this may be different in different versions of Windows, as David pointed up) there's a list of values in the registry that keep track of the executable name and its associated last "visited" path.

The list can be found in this key:

`HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32\LastVisitedPidlMRU`

In order to reset the default open/save path for a particular program, you have to find the value whose data string (UNICODE) starts with your executable name and delete it. If you watch at the data string, you'll notice that the last used path is there, after the executable name.